# Folder permissions getting changed when folder is deployed through FTP in cloud 9 IDE

Tags: permissions, ftp, cloud9-ide

I am trying to deploy a folder using 'Deploy to FTP Server' option in cloud9 IDE. Folder got deployed correctly on the remote location. But when I tried to access the files in folder I encountered error `403 Forbidden. You do not have permission to access this document`.When checked through console, permissions got changed. It is not feasible to change the folder permissions each time. What should I do?
Any help will be highly appreciated.